# Error anexing JSON data with Swift 2

Tags: ios, arrays, json, swift, dictionary

I'm working in an iOS App (using Swift2) and I have some problems including JSON data to the App. For the "Sign Up" I'm using mobile-number verification (like whatsapp), so when I'm using the following JSON data (http://data.okfn.org/data/core/country-codes/r/country-codes.json) to shows the Country and the Dial code of each one in a tableView, it shows me an error.

I'm writing this code:

---

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.

    let urlPath = "http://data.okfn.org/data/core/country-codes/r/country-codes.json"
    let url = NSURL(string: urlPath)
    let session = NSURLSession.sharedSession()
    let task = session.dataTaskWithURL(url!, completionHandler: { data, response, error -> Void in
        if (error != nil) {
            print(error)
        } else {
            do {
                let jsonResult = try NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data!, options: NSJSONReadingOptions.AllowFragments)
                print(jsonResult["name"])
            } catch _ {}
        }
    })
    task.resume()
}
```

}

---

The debug area shows this:

---

```
    {
    DS = AL;
    Dial = 355;
    FIFA = ALB;
    FIPS = AL;
    GAUL = 3;
    IOC = ALB;
    "ISO3166-1-Alpha-2" = AL;
    "ISO3166-1-Alpha-3" = ALB;
    "ISO3166-1-numeric" = 008;
    ITU = ALB;
    MARC = aa;
    WMO = AB;
    "currency_alphabetic_code" = ALL;
    "currency_country_name" = ALBANIA;
    "currency_minor_unit" = 2;
    "currency_name" = Lek;
    "currency_numeric_code" = 008;
    "is_independent" = Yes;
    name = Albania;
    "name_fr" = Albanie;
},
```

---

So, is there other way to access just the Name of the country and the Dial code? I don't know why it shows me an error/nil

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`jsonResult` is an array of dictionaries. An array cannot be subscripted by key, that causes the error.

This code replacing the `do - catch` part prints the names and dial codes of all countries. The dictionary type can even be constrained to `[String:String]`

```
do {
   let jsonResult = try NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data!, options: NSJSONReadingOptions.AllowFragments) as! [[String:String]]
   for country in jsonResult {
      print(country["name"]!, country["Dial"]!)
   }
} catch let error as NSError { print(error) }
```